# Why do I get ”mount error(1): Operation not permitted“ on ”mount.cifs“ in a LXC container on a Proxmox VE machine?

Tags: mount, samba, lxc, proxmox

I've set up a new Debian 9 (*stretch*) LXC container on a machine running Proxmox VE, and installed the `cifs-utils` package.
I quickly tested the connection to the SMB server by running

```
smbclient //192.168.0.2/share -U myusername
```

which worked fine. However, the command

```
mount.cifs //192.168.0.2/share /mnt -o user=myusername
```

failed, printing the following error message:

```
mount error(1): Operation not permitted
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I've made sure that…

- the **owner** and **group** of the shared directory (on the SMB server, which is a FreeBSD machine) are both existent on the client, i.e., inside the container.
- the **owner** of the shared directory is a member of the **group**, both on the server and the client. (`id myusername`)
- the mountpoint (`/mnt`) exists on the client.

What could be the cause of the above-mentioned error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're probably running an **unprivileged** LXC container. The easiest solution is to use a **privileged** container instead. However, there might be other solutions; take a look e.g. at [this thread/post](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/presenting-a-cifs-share-to-a-container.37195/#post-182890) in the proxmox forums.

Answer (score 2):

I am not using any Containers, but on my Debian Workstation a have had a similar error a few weeks ago.

After some research I found a solution for me.

I had to add `vers=2.0` to the options of the mount command.

Answer (score 2):

Try using all variables mentioned below.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //<IPAddress>/<FromDirectory> /<ToDirectory> -o uid=xxx,username="xxxxx",password="xxxxx",domain="xxxxx",sec=ntlm,vers=2.0
```